# using lambda together with a condition statement

Tags: python, lambda

This is my code to check if the value of getBonus() is above 5000 after i add 100 to the numder using lambda. lets say if i must use lambda method, how can i use a condition statement such as if-else to check whether the value is more or lesser than 5000?

```
 bonus=1000
    getBonus= lambda x:x+100
    if x>5000:
     return x+bonus*2
    else:
     return x+bonus
    print getBonus(3000)
    print getBonus(6000)
```

it keeps saying return is out of the function which i assumed it is referring to the lambda expression

Comment: Where's the function definition?

Comment: Where is `x` initially assigned?

Comment: the code is bad (maybe that's why the OP is asking for help and SO always ask to show some code, and I like it so) but the explanation is correct. Not so bad after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is incorrect but I'm getting the idea.

This is possible with a lambda but a bit twisted (because you have to test x against 5000 but added 100. Using a ternary is the key:

```
bonus=1000
getBonus = lambda x: x+100+bonus*2 if x>4900 else x+100+bonus
print(getBonus(3000))
print(getBonus(4950))
print(getBonus(4900))
print(getBonus(6000))
```

result:

```
4100
7050
6000
8100
```

I think I got the formula & test OK. Tests indicate so, but just the fact that I'm doubting means that creating a lambda for that is not a very good idea unless you can't do otherwise.

EDIT: proof that's a bad idea: I had to fix the lambda because it was wrong (5100 => 4900). Here's the regular function definition. I'd rather go for that one:

```
def getBonus(x):
    x += 100
    return x+bonus*2 if x>5000 else x+bonus
```

Comment: Perhaps add a *regular* function definition.

Comment: @DarrylDan please check update. The lambda had a bug. The lambda made me pre-compute the limit wrong. Fixed